# rail ajax remote form to update text field upon submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

All I want to do is update a text field on my page with a value when my Rails remote form is submitted.

All the source code be found at github here https://github.com/iamliamnorton/fasdac

The form is on the index page...

Controller code...

```
def index

  @calculator = Calculator.new(params[:calculator])
  if @calculator.valid?
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to calculator_path(:calculator => params[:calculator]), :notice => 'Calculation was successfully completed.' }
      format.js
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to calculator_path(:calculator => params[:calculator]), :alert => "Calculation was not successfully completed. #{@calculator.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}" }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

My input form

```
<%= form_for(@calculator, :url => calculator_path, :remote => true) do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

And the index.js.erb

```
$("#result").value = "SUCCESS!";
```

I'm trying to update a input text field with name and id 'result'. I cannot get this working, I've tried many different variants in the index.js.erb but cannot get it working. What am I doing wrong?

It looks like the data is being sent to the controller as I can see in the server console

```
...
Processing by CalculatorController#index as JS
...
```

But I can't get the text area to update

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$('#result').val("Success!");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**index.js.erb**

```
$('#result').val("Success!");
```